# Nginx incorrect locations handling

Tags: configuration, web, nginx

How to properly handle all non-existent locations in nginx configuration for php site?
I can figure out 5 possible cases of such locations.

1. Incorrect files: *example.com/notexist.jpg*
2. Incorrect folders: *example.com/notexist*
3. Nested incorrect folders: *example.com/notexist1/notexist2/..../notexist10000*
4. Combination of (3) and (1): *example.com/notexist1/notexist2/..../notexist10000/not.exist.jpg*
5. Non-existent php files: *example.com/notexist.php*

Is there tiny and powerful solution covering all of these cases?
Also need to avoid checking ANY file and dir (with -d and -f) as it will add CPU and IO overhead.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try_files** solves the issue completely for me

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}
```

It is also very important to have absolute paths in your not_found_page otherwise page layout will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

in all your 5 cases a 404 would normally be returned, so you can add special handling of all those cases by:

1. creating a named location
2. referring to that named location as your 404 error page:

that would yield:

```
server {      
  error_page 404 = @errors;

  location @fallback {
    # do whatever you want to do on faulty reqeusts
  }
}
```